# How to merge row processing kernel filterring and column processing kernel filterring into single openCL kernel

Tags: c, optimization, opencl

I have image processing filter implemented using row and column processing in openCL, Where most of the processing gets wasted in launching multiple kernels itself.

So Can i merge these two kernel into single kernel which do the same functionality and performs better in Intel HD4600 graphics card. Details of the code is given below:-

Assumptions:
 
1. Both horizontal and vertical padding is done by host (c programming)
2. N (filter length is 8, width and height are 1024 x 1024,filter coefficients are generated using generic filters 
3. First row and then col Kernel is being launched using  below API
 
ret |= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global_ws(1024x1024), NULL, 0, NULL,NULL);

//Code:

```
__kernel void filter_rows(__global float *ip_img,__global float *op_img,
                          int width, int height,int pitch,int N,__constant float *W)
{
    __private int i=get_global_id(0); 
    __private int j=get_global_id(1); 
    __private int k;
    __private float a;
    __private int image_offset = N*pitch +N;
    __private int curr_pix = j*pitch + i +image_offset;
    // apply filter
    for(k=-N, a=0.0f; k<=N; k++)
    {
    a += ip_img[curr_pix+k] * W[k+N];
    }
    op_img[curr_pix] = a;   
}
__kernel void filter_col(__global float *ip_img,__global float *op_img,int width,
                         int height,int pitch,int N,__constant float *W)
{
    __private int i=get_global_id(0);
    __private int j=get_global_id(1);
    __private int k;
    __private float a;
    __private int image_offset = N*pitch +N;
    __private int curr_pix = j*pitch + i +image_offset;

    // apply filter
    for(k=-N, a=0.0f; k<=N; k++)
    {
      a += ip_img[k*pitch +curr_pix] * W[k+N];                  
    }
    op_img[curr_pix] = a;
}
void padd_hor(float *ip_img,pad_leng)
{
    //...using simple C programming
}
void padd_ver(float *ip_img,pad_leng)
{
    //...using simple c programming
}
void generic_filter(_global float *in_image,__global float *out_image,
__global float *temp_image,int width, int height,int pitch,int N,
__constant float *Wr,__constant float *Wc)
{
    padd_hor(in_image,filter_length)
    filter_rows(in_image,temp_image,width,height,pitch,filter_length,filter_coeff_hor);
    pad_ver(temp_image,filter_length)
    filter_col(temp_image,out_image,width,height,pitch,filter_length,filter_coeff_ver);
}
__kernel generic_filter(_global float *in_image,__global float *out_image,__global      float*temp_image,
int width, int height,int pitch,int N,__constant float *Wr,__constant float *Wc)
{
    // ... here i need your suggetion to implement the kernel which do same as generic_filter
}
```

Your help will be appreciated to optimize this filter and  get the best possible result.
Also please let me know how much max gain can i  get with respect to C code runs on Intel CPU.

Thanks and Regards 
Vijayky88

Comment: I wouldn't merge it, your are doing rectangular image filtering. That type of algorithm is suited for separate passes, Row and Col, so two separate calls is the easyer and faster thing you can do. What you should do is add local memory to it, since the neighbours WIs read overlapped memory regions. Also, the Order of the dimensions (X,Y) or (Y,X) may affect the coalescence, check that as well.

Comment: Agreed. Separable filters must be run sequentially, which means you can't do the passes together in a single kernel (since you can't do global synchronization). You'll find that your optimized vertical pass is faster than your optimized horizontal pass due to coalesced reads. The solution is to add a rotation pass which allows you to use the vertical pass twice. The rotation must use shared local memory to make both the reads and writes fast.

Comment: Just an update we are getting the gain using above technique,but not as per expectation. Actually i am looking gain min of 2x performance improvement.Please suggest your idea.
I all ready try merging of these two using 16x16 blocks processing but no gain observed.

Comment: Supplying N as a compile time constant might help as well.